# fancybox2 iframe scrolling on ipad with mobile safari

Tags: ipad, iframe, safari, scroll, fancybox

Does anyone know an easy fix to make scrolling possible when using an iframe and fancybox2?  The ipad, using mobile safari, still does not appear to allow scrollbars or touch scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Do not show scrolls, just open fancybox with the height of the frame content, then user will scroll through popup as he does in usual window.

In the iframe template add mobile metas:

```
        <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
        <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

Call fancybox like this:

```
   if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
       $("a.fancybox").fancybox({
            'scrolling' : 'yes',
            'type'      : 'iframe',
            'autoSize'  : true,
            'autoResize': true,
            'fitToView' : false 
        });
   }
```

You might want to set the width.

That works for me.